# The meaning of "sold at option"

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the meaning of "sold at option". Does it mean that whether the thing will be sold or not is uncertain? An example sentence is

> AAA, sold 20% of their company,and the other 80% could be **sold at option** in 2021

Comment: It means that the buyers could have  the option (possibility) to buy the remaining  80 per cent in 2021.

Comment: I think we need a real quote and context to know what this means. “Sell at auction” is a well-used phrase but “sell at option” isn’t.

Answer (score 1):

This is referencing [stock options](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/stockoption.asp):

> A stock option gives an investor the right, but not the obligation, to buy or sell a stock at an agreed upon price and date.

So I read your quote:

> AAA, sold 20% of their company,and the other 80% could be sold at option in 2021

to mean that when AAA sold their company they relinquished %20 of their stock immediately.  They also provided the investor with the option to purchase the remaining 80% of the company in 2021 at a set price.  The excerpt is saying that this option could be exercised by the investors in this deal, which is expressed here as "sold at option".